# Statically link shared library using go build

Tags: c, go

I need to create a static library to run it in a docker container. When running my code with `go run main.go` it just runs smoothly. However, things get complicated when I try to build my code as a **static** program (re-compile all dynamic dependencies into a standalone lib, including shared libraries).

My app depends on a C shared library located in my `/usr/local/lib/librandom_c.so`, while my app source code is located in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/<user>/myapp`.

When I build the app **without** trying to statically link the shared library, it works without complaining:

```
go build -a -o hello .
```

...but then docker complains that the shared library does not exist (using from scratch).

So far I have tried many combinations to statically build my app:

```
go build -a -ldflags '-linkmode "external" -extldflags "-static"' -o hello .
```

gives an error:

> cannot find -lrandom_c

How do I statically link my lib?

Comment: Is copying the lib to the docker image not possible?

Comment: Do you have a copy of `librandom_c.a`?

Comment: @Nick not really, as I use `scratch` as docker image and it has literally nothing. Meaning there is no `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` concept etc... Even putting my lib here, the program will still try to find it using dynamic strategies that don't exist in `scratch`.

Comment: @JL2210 I do have a copy of `librandom_c.a`, can this help in some way ?

Comment: @JonaRodrigues Place it in `/usr/local/lib/`.

Comment: I placed `librandom_c.a` into my `/use/local/lib/` and it now complains like crazy with a bunch of `undefined reference to <some_random_function_here>` and ends with `collect 2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. Really I have no clue of what it means (I am not the author of the lib neither the go bindings to it).

Comment: I don't know if that means my issue is "solved" and the issue is now on the go package side (maybe linking things incorrectly) or if that's a compiler Error... Muy doubt is maybe I should use some kind of magic flags in the `go build` to instruct go where to look. In fact, maybe my reasoning doesn't makes sense, but I assume that if `go run` works, there should be a way to tell `go build` to kinda sniff all dependencies found while using `go run` and include them. I have read a lot about this but I can't find the magic flags...

Comment: If you run `ldd /usr/local/lib/librandom_c.so`, does it have other library dependencies?  (You intrinsically can't statically link to a dynamic-link library; the ordering of the C compiler `-l` options is extremely order-sensitive for static libraries.  You could also build a dynamically linked binary and use an `alpine` or `ubuntu` Docker base image with the infrastructure required to use it.)

Comment: Yeah actually there are some 10 other libraries `librandom_c.so` depends on as I see using `ldd` (thanks by the way, I didn't know that command). I tried to use `alpine` but the library depends on `libgcc` and `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` which are not supported by `musl` (compiler used by `alpine`)... Ubuntu + gcc would make the trick but then it would defeat the purpose of what I am trying to do which is create a standalone portable program. I am quite not sure of what you mean by "you can't statically link to a dynamic-link library" since I happen to see go programs doing it.

Answer (score 2):

[CL 26492](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26492) shows that it might be as simple (possible for Go 1.14 Q1 2020, not confirmed yet) as to do:

```
go build -static
```

That would encapsulate the magic incantations of:

- windows: `-tags netgo -ldflags '-H=windowsgui -extldflags "-static"'`
- linux/bsd: `-tags netgo -ldflags '-extldflags "-static"'`
- macos: `-ldflags '-s -extldflags "-sectcreate __TEXT __info_plist Info.plist"'`
- android: `-ldflags -s`